# Logical operator PHP variable equals A or B or C, it dose not evaluate as either of them

Tags: php, arrays, ftp, logical-operators

I am currently using ftp_rawlist to output every file and folder including subfolders in the root directory of a remote site. The output of the files in the array include the permissions, the user etc

e.g from var_Dump

```
string(68) "-rw-r--r--    1 XXXX   XXXX         1754 Sep 13 12:13 run.js"
```

I run through the array of files and folders in a foreach loop, I grab the last occurance of a space to isolate the file and folder name using strrchr function. I then trim the whitespace and finally using the if statement

```
  <?php     
      if($newfilename != ".." || $newfilename != "."   $newfilename != "")  {

         echo $newfilename."</br>";
         var_dump($newfilename);
     }
     ?>
```

I expect it to output files and folders in the array that don't contain ".." or "." "" But it still outputs anyway. Any help please?

```
  array(".", "..", "name.txt")
```

just output

name.txt

instead of

., .., name.txt

Answer (score 3):

Your conditions should be `&&`, not `||`:

```
if ($newfilename != ".." && $newfilename != "."  && $newfilename != "")  {
    // file name is not '..', '.' or ''
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if(($newfilename != "..") && ($newfilename != ".") && ($newfilename != ""))  {
    // 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorter:

```
if(!in_array($newfilename,["..",".",""]))  {
```

Shorter & absolutely dirty

```
!in_array($newfilename,["..",".",""]) && !echo $newfilename."</br>" &&  var_dump($newfilename);
```

(echo doesn't return any value, so negate null is true, hence execute var_dump)